# How to get rid of an extra status bar?

Tags: ios, swift, uikit

So, I have a UITableViewController which is presented modally. Tapping on a cell launches a full-screen player (AVPlayerViewController). It is presented with `self.presentViewController(...)`.

Everything works fine except there is now an extra status bar displayed. When you tap on the player view, only one of these two gets hidden.

```
func play (url: NSURL, time: NSTimeInterval) {

    let asset = AVURLAsset(URL: url)
    let playerItem = AVPlayerItem(asset: asset)
    let player = AVPlayer(playerItem: playerItem)
    let playerController = AVPlayerViewController()
    playerController.player = player

    playerController.modalPresentationStyle = .OverFullScreen

    presentViewController(playerController, animated: true) {
        player.seekToTime(CMTime(seconds: time, preferredTimescale:
            playerItem.currentTime().timescale))
            player.play()
    }

}
```

I tried setting modal presentation style to `.OverFullScreen`. It didn't help.

EDIT:

To make things clear, let me attach a few screenshots.

When I present the player VC, it looks like that. As you can see there are two status bars overlayed one on another.

[image: player vc before tapping on the player view]

When I tap on the player view only one of them disappears.
[image: player vc after tapping on the player view]

What I want is to have only one status bar (which gets hidden after tapping as it should), not two.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a way to solve this issue. It's more of a hacky workaround though.

1) First I set `View controller-based status bar appearance` to `YES` in Info.plist since I want to be explicit about this (I guess, `YES` is the default anyway).

2) I added a boolean property in the view controller which presented the above mentioned `UITableViewController` modally (let's call it "Back VC" from now on).

```
var statusBarHidden = false {
    didSet {
        self.setNeedsStatusBarAppearanceUpdate()
    }
}
```

3) I've overridden `prefersStatusBarHidden` so it returns whatever is stored in the variable from the second step.

```
override func prefersStatusBarHidden() -> Bool {
    return statusBarHidden
}
```

4) Assuming `backVC` points to the "Back VC", I added a few changes to `presentViewController`'s completion block. Basically, I make the "Back VC" hide its status bar so we only have the one managed by `AVPlayerViewController`.

```
presentViewController(playerController, animated: true) {
     if UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == .Pad {
        backVC.statusBarHidden = true
     }
     player.seekToTime(CMTime(seconds: time, preferredTimescale:
         playerItem.currentTime().timescale))
         player.play()
}
```

5) When the player is dismissed we need to get back our original status bar. A good place to do it is our modal VC's `viewWillAppear`.

```
override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)
    if UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == .Pad {
        backVC.statusBarHidden = false
    }
}
```

It works but surely doesn't feel right. If you know a better solution feel free to share.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get rid of the status bar completely:

```
func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {
     application.statusBarHidden = true
     return true
}
```

Or if you want to get rid of the status bar in a view just add

```
UIApplication.sharedApplication().setStatusBarHidden(true, withAnimation: .None)
```

in your `viewDidLoad`.

Comment: I'm afraid it doesn't solve the problem. I edited my original post with a few screenshots.

Comment: So you want to remove the status bar that shows the clock etc and keep the statusbar that shows the video progress?

Comment: not really. I'd like to remove the second status bar with clock etc. As you can see from the second screenshot one gets hidden on tap as it should and the other (you can tell it from the battery indicator showing up) is still there.

Comment: On the second screenshot, can´t you do the `UIApplication.sharedApplication().setStatusBarHidden(true, withAnimation: .None) `?

Comment: ```setStatusBarHidden``` is deprecated in iOS 9. As an alternative, there is a method on UIViewController that can be overridden "prefersStatusBarHidden -> Bool". I tried but nothing changed though.